# Webpack: Plugin's "emit" callback not being called

Tags: npm, webpack

I created a simple webpack plugin that does work at `emit` stage, however, the `emit` callback doesn't seem to be executed. The odd thing is this works on my machine but not on a different machine. Here's the snippet of my code.

```
HashedJsSourceInjector.prototype.apply = function(compiler) {
  var outputName = this.opts.fileName;
  var cache = this.opts.cache || {};

  cosole.log("Entered.."); 

  compiler.plugin('emit', function(compilation, compileCallback) {

    console.log("Never entered...");

...

    compileCallback();

  } 

}
```

What could be wrong?

UPDATE:

My webpack and npm versions are `1.13.1` and `3.9.3` respectively.

I've checked both are on the same version on our QA server. The only difference is that the QA server is running CentOS and my PC is running Ubuntu.